# fread не записывает в массив данные из бинарного файла

Tags: c, файлы

В правильности записанных данных убедился просмотрев их через 16-ричный редактор.
Поэтому смело открываю файл на чтение

```
FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\seven\\source\\repos\\NeCuda\\NeCuda\\input.bin", "rb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open up file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Сосчитал количество байтов записанных в бинарный файл и разделил на то, сколько занимает один байт,чтобы узнать кол-во элементов массива.

```
while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)
        counter++;
    counter /= sizeof(int);
```

Выделил соответствующее кол-во памяти и проверил , что правда ли выделилось памяти

```
temp = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*counter);
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot give mem");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Теперь хочу записать в ново-созданный массив данные из файла

```
int k=fread(temp, sizeof(int), counter, fp);
```

Но ничего не записывается , указатель(как показывается отладчик) указывает на мусор(висячий).
fread вернул 0 и записал этот нуль в *k* - значит точно fread не сработал.Как сделать так, чтобы fread записывал в temp данные из файла?

Следовал советам ниже:

```
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
counter=ftell(fp);
temp = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*counter);
if (temp == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot give mem");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
int k=fread(temp, sizeof(int), counter, fp);
show(temp);
```

Но всё равно нет резульата

В отладчике вижу,что указатель такой:
fp  0x000002c9f7afc840 {_Placeholder=0x0000000000000000 }

Comment: дык, а поток то перемотал после первого прочтения?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, да,дошло уже

Comment: ещё чтобы определить размер файла обычно используют комбинацию `fseek()`/`ftell()`

Comment: `counter` у вас теперь размер в байтах; а вам нужен - в `int`'ах.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После первого прочтения вы вышли на конец файла.

Последующая попытка `fread` обращается за конец файла - и, понятно, ничего прочесть не в состоянии.

Вам нужно вернуться в начало файла с помощью функции [`fseek`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek).

Более того, вот это

```
while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    counter++;
```

можно было бы заменить на

```
fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
counter = ftell(fp);
```

Comment: rewind поможет?

Comment: Да, так как это синоним вызова `fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_SET);`. Но если, скажем, у вас сначала шел бы какой-то заголовок, т.е. вам надо было бы читать не с самого начала - то `fseek` более универсальна. Более того, вы могли бы не читать все эти символы по одному, а просто вызвать `fseek` и стать в конец файла, а `ftell` сказало бы вам его размер...

Comment: ,fseek и rewind не помогли , по-прежнему не считывается

Comment: Убедитесь сами, что все OK: https://ideone.com/lW7EGF Тут я только дописал кусок создания файла для проверки.

Comment: Вот вам второй вариант - с fseek/ftell - https://ideone.com/3Jrube

Comment: ,дошло, спасибо